# Unable to update registry with byteorder

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have an error when I execute `cargo run`. I added the line `byteorder = "0.3.13"` to my Cargo.toml, and here is the output of `cargo run --verbose`:

```
Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
Unable to update registry https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index

Caused by:
failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
[9] Object not found - failed to find pack entry (c7c0b5bc32630012be674d1cacd1487d09a2c0b5)
```

When I remove the line, everything is ok. How do I fix this error?

Comment: It looks like the index repository is broken for some reason. Consider removing `~/.cargo/registry/index/github.com-xxxxxx` and running the build again. Or you can remove `~/.cargo` directory completely and start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I already have done this, always the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed ! I just reinstalled rust nightly with multirust :)